# I can't find the mistake in my proof

Tags: solution-verification, power-series, fake-proofs

I thought about something in power series and I proved a theorem that I have never seen before:
**The theorem:**

> Let $\begin{align} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^n \end{align}$ be a power series, with a convergence range of $R$(doesn't matter if its closed, open, half closed half open, or half open halp closed range). For every $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ sequence that has only a finite number of elements that satisfy $x_n\notin R$, then the series $\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx_n^n\end{align}$ converges.

**The proof:**

> Let $\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n, \{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\end{align}$ as in the wording. We  will define $A\subset\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n,x_{n+1},\cdots\}$ be the group of elements that are not in the range of $R$. i.e if $x_i\in A$, then $x_i\notin R$. Now we will look at $A$: $A=\{x_{1^{'}},x_{2^{'}},\cdots,x_{m^{'}}\}$. We know that $|A|\in\mathbb{N}$, which means $m^{'}\in\mathbb{N}$. From here, we will look at the series: $\begin{align}\sum_{n=m^{'}+1}^\infty a_nx_n^n\end{align}$.
> We know that this series converges because every $j>m{'}$ satisfies $x_j\in R$.
> But we know that $\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\end{align}$ converges iff  $\begin{align}\sum_{n=m}^\infty b_n\end{align}$ converges. So we will define $b_n=a_nx_n^n$, and $m=m^{'}+1$.
> And so $\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx_n^n\end{align}$ converges iff  $\begin{align}\sum_{n=m^{'}+1}^\infty a_nx_n^n\end{align}$ converges, which means $\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx_n^n\end{align}$ converges.$\square$

The problem is that I found a contradiction to my theorem, so I think that I made a mistake in my proof, but I can't find where it is.
**The contradiction:**

> The convergence range of $\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}\end{align}$ is $R=[-1,1)$. I'll choose $x_n=(1.01)^{-\frac{1}{n}}$. It's easy to see that for every $n>0$ we get $x_n\in R$. So by the theorem, the series $\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{{({(1.01)}^{-\frac{1}{n}})}^n}{n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1.01^{-1}}{n}=\frac{1}{1.01}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \end{align}$ should converge, but it is obviously does not.

*Note* - Other than helping me with finding out what's the problem with my proof, if you know about some similar theorem please let me know.

Comment: Title should be informative about the math content of your post, not genetic and about you.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Do you have an idea for a title? Becuase writing the whole theorem is too long for a title, don't you think?

Comment: I didn't say to put the whole problem, but to put something relevant to the math. "Find the mistake in this proof" is both generic and uninformative, and will prove completely useless to anyone searching in  the future. All you need is to indicate (1) it is about convergence of a series obtained from a power series, and (2) you want help in locating the mistake.

Comment: And if you have an example that contradicts your conclusion, then you should apply the argument to your example: that should highlight where the error is, when your argument says something wrong about your explicit example.

Comment: If your text stated the theorem using the subscript $n$ for those $x$'s not in $R$, that is terrible indeed. And it leads to all sorts of confusion. Use a different letter there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We know that this series converges because every $j>m'$ satisfies $x_j\in R$.

Here is the problem. You are forming the sum $\sum_{n=m'+1}^\infty a_nx_n^n$, where each individual term $a_n x_n^n$ is taken from a convergent series $\sum_{k=m'+1}^\infty a_k x_n^k$, but that isn't sufficient to establish convergence of the series. As you know, you can remove any finitely many terms from a series without affecting convergence, so you get basically no control over individual terms. As a crude example, if we fix any $k \in \Bbb{N}$, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \delta_{nk}$ converges to $1$, where $\delta_{nk}$ is equal to $1$ when $n = k$, and $0$ otherwise. But, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \delta_{nn} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1 = \infty$.

But, I can see that convergence in this case looks more *plausible* than the generalisation of your reasoning, given that all these points lie within the radius of convergence. Your counterexample shows that even this is not enough, however. If your $x_n$s approach an open edge of your interval of convergence quickly enough, then your series may approximate the edge case divergent series better than it approximates any of the convergent series it samples from.

Comment: But that's the point. i'm trying to say that the series $\begin{align}\sum_{n=m^{'}+1}^\infty a_nx_n^n\end{align}$ converges, not the series $\begin{align}\sum_{n=m^{'}+1}^\infty a_kx_n^n\end{align}$. I didn't by accident gave them the same "index character", that is the entire point of what I thought, and I still didn't get why it is not correct

Comment: One more thing, do you think maybe with some other conditions, I could make a theorem like this one? Maybe if the original $\sum a_nx^n$ converges uniformly, or something else? Because the thing is I started to think about this when I was trying to determine whether or not series like $\sum \frac{2\sin(n)+3\cos^2(\frac{n}{6})}{n^2}$ converge. Because it can be useful(even with some conditions)

Comment: @Chessplayer I am aware you are considering $\sum_{n=m' + 1}^\infty a_n x_n^n$. The highlighted assertion is unsupported (and, as your example shows, false in general), but my guess as to how you were reasoning this step internally may have been wrong. Why, specifically, do you believe the highlighted sentence to be true (or plausible)? The other series $\sum_{k=m'+1}^\infty a_k x_n^k$ converges for any $n$, and the series you consider is the "diagonal" series, summing one term from each of the convergent series, but there's no reason to think that diagonal series must converge.

Comment: @Chessplayer I do think some kind of weaker result is possible here. If you could show that the series converges absolutely at $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$, then it should be easy to show the series in question will converge. You might be able to place restrictions on $x_n$ to make sure it increases sufficiently slowly, relative to the $a_n$s, so that the series converges. There should be some results there.

Comment: @Chessplayer I wouldn't necessarily go that far. My guess would be that it won't work without assuming absolute convergence at $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$, but I haven't thought it through.